# Для чего мы используем isinstance(x, list):

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, типы

Пример из учебника по питону:

```
def sumtree(L):
    tot = 0
    for x in L:   # Обход элементов одного уровня     
        if not isinstance(x, list):
            tot += x           # Числа суммируются непосредственно
        else:
            tot += sumtree(x)  # Списки обрабатываются рекурсивными вызовами
    return tot
```

Далее:

```
 print(sumtree([1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]))  #получаем 15 на выходе
```

Вопрос: Почему нам так важно включить в условие:

> > if not isinstance(x, list):
> > tot += x

Я хочу понять логику работы. Пожалуйста объясните почему мы должны написать код именно таким образом?

Comment: `isinstance(x, list)` это проверка на то является ли `x` списком

Answer (score 6):

В вашей задачи происходит сложение **простых значений** в списках **с вложенными списками**, поэтому нужна проверка типа значения, чтобы понять чем является значение и что с ним нужно делать.

Такой проверкой `if not isinstance(x, list)` проверяется, что `x` не является списком, чтобы можно было без ошибок сложить значение `x` с счетчиком `tot`. А если `x` является списком, то отправить его в рекурсию, чтобы внутри нее перебрать этот список и вернуть сумму по счетчику

---

Например, у вас среди значений есть наглядный `[4, [5]]`. При переборе в цикле в `x` сначала будет `4`, а на следующей итерации будет `[5]`:

- при `x = 4`, проверка `isinstance(x, list)` будет `False`, и значение `4` будет прибавлено к `tot`
- при `x = [5]`, проверка `isinstance(x, list)` будет `True`, и значение `[5]` будет отправлено в `sumtree`. В функции оно в цикле будет перебираться и там `x = 5` будет прибавлено в `tot`, цикл закончится и функция вернет `5`, оно прибавится к `tot` в текущей функции для `[4, [5]]` и снова завершится функция и вернется `9` (т.к. `4` + `5` в `[4, [5]]`)

Попробуйте:

```
print(sumtree([4, [5]]))
```