# isinstance python

Tags: python

В каких случаях нужно использовать isinstance в Python? Утиная типизация все спишет в функциях и методах, или есть конкретные моменты?

Comment: Что она спишет:-)? Вот вам пример использования с пояснением, зачем: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1228133/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC-isinstancex-list>

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что ответ можно найти в анналах документации по Python. В действительности данная функциональность редко встречается в пользовательских классах. Но есть одно хорошее НО: если вы это не используете, это совершенно не значит, что это никому не нужно.

Приведу перевод из [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=isinstance#how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-given-class-or-of-a-subclass-of-it) официальной документации.

> How do I check if an object is an instance of a given class or of a subclass of it?
>
> > **Перевод**: как мне проверить, является ли объект экземпляром данного класса или его подкласса

> Use the built-in function isinstance(obj, cls).
>
> > **Перевод**: Используйте встроенную функцию isinstance(obj, cls)

Вот такой ответ. Сомневаться в нужности той или иной конструкции не приходится, пока не появляются примеры и практика их использования, так называемые `best practices`. Если вам *нужно* проверить, является ли объект экземпляром данного класса или его подкласса, тогда *используйте*. Лаконично.

Далее по тексту документации встречается такая оговорка, которая уточняет ОО стиль

> If you are developing the classes yourself, a more proper object-oriented style is to define methods on the classes that encapsulate a particular behaviour, instead of checking the object’s class and doing a different thing based on what class it is
>
> > **Перевод** Если вы разрабатываете собственные классы, то более правильным объектно-ориентированным стилем будет определение методов класса, которые инкапсулируют конкретное поведение, вместо того, чтобы проверять объект класса и выполнять различные действия в зависимости от того, какой это класс

Пример, вместо вот такого использования:

```py
def search(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Mailbox):
        ...  # code to search a mailbox
    elif isinstance(obj, Document):
        ...  # code to search a document
    elif ..
```

Делай так

```py
class Mailbox:
    def search(self):
        ...  # code to search a mailbox

class Document:
    def search(self):
        ...  # code to search a document

obj.search()
```